# static factory methods inside interface

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

This is a design question regarding using static factory methods inside of static interface methods. I am looking for improvements or disadvantages of using this pattern.

```
public interface SampleService {

    // 1) do work
    void doWork();

    static SampleService create(final String service) {
        // 2)  Dispatch to factory method to get correct implementation
        return Factory.create(service);
    }

    class Factory {
        private static SampleService create(final String service) {
            // 3) return one of many possible implementations
            return new DefaultSampleService();
        }
    }

    class DefaultSampleService implements SampleService {
        @Override
        public void doWork() {
            // 4)  performs work
        }
    }
}
```

In original implementation, caller would call

> SampleService.Factory.create

now they call it as

> SampleService.create

Which looks to be cleaner and more readable.
So what could we improve on this?

Comment: Why not just create the `DefaultSampleService' directly in `SampleService.create` method and not define `Factory` class?

Comment: This is an oversimplified version of `create`. The real implementation is actually a little bit more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **not** to put the factory into the Interface for the following reason:

It **violates** the Open-Closed-principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

A client, working with the Interface `SampleService`, doesn't wan't that the Interface(file) to change frequently. That is always a source of errors.

A factory method in an Interface is therefore not a good programming style (in my opinion). I suggest to split the Interface and Factory into two different classes. Possible clients don't have to know if new subtypes are created and in that way the *volatile* part of the program is capsulate in the Factory class.

Comment: Can you provide a link that shows that client has to be recompile when a new factory is added to the interface?

Comment: The client is dependent on the interface. If the Interface changes, the client has to recompile. It is nothing special to factories.

Comment: The interface methods don't change or get added/removed. It is the nested class that changes and according to your answer client needs to be recompiled when interface's nested class changes.

Comment: You compile a source file, not a class. Any classes, including nested ones, in that source file are compiled.

Comment: Okay i'am sorry, I thought this was C++. I'am not sure how Java managed that. However, from the design view, my answer remains the same. I will edit the compiling path.